# No results found error in Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parseexception

I am using Parse in my android application. My aim is to retrieve all the names of quizTitle in my Class CSE_1234 for which the status is "no". But I am getting ParseException: No results found 
Here is my code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery,getQuery("CSE_1234");
query.whereEqualTo("status","no");
query.get("quizTitle");
List<ParseObject> activeQuizTitle=query.find();
String title[]=(String[]) activeQuizTitle.toArray();
return title
```

Answer (score 0):

couple things are wrong in your codes

- remove query.get(), this is supposed to load the object by Id
- you cannot cast List to String[]
- do a for loop and ParseObject.getString("title");

Comment: Alright. I'll try that but how do I get all the quizTitle in the class then?

Comment: `String[] titles = new String[activeQuizTitle.size()]; for(int i=0;i< activeQuizTitle.size();i++) {titiles[i] = activeQuizTitle.getString("title");}`

Comment: The method getString(string) is undefined for the type List<ParseObject>

Comment: activeQuizTitle.get(i).getString("title")

Answer (score 0):

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery,getQuery("CSE_1234");
```

This should be:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("CSE_1234");
```

you have a comma (`,`) where there should be a period (`.`) between `ParseQuery` and `getQuery`